# How to resolve error NG0500 During hydration Angular expected <ion-toolbar> but found a comment node

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic7, angular-ssr

I am using Angular (17.2) and Ionic (7.7.4) in an NX monorepo.
However experiencing the following issues:

```
▲ [WARNING] The glob pattern import("./**/*.entry.js*") did not match any files [empty-glob]                                                          

    node_modules/@stencil/core/internal/client/index.js:4019:4:
      4019 │     `./${bundleId}.entry.js${BUILD.hotModuleReplacement && hmrVe...
```

as well as
`error-handler.service.ts:11 Error: NG0500: During hydration Angular expected <ion-toolbar> but found a comment node.`

I am expecting that Ionic supports Angulars SSR

Answer (score 0):

With Angular standalone components, you cannot use IonicModule :

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
```

you need to import elements individually :

```
import { IonButton, IonMenu, etc. } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';
```

and then list them in component's imports:[]

Comment: What makes you think, that I am using IonicModule in a first place? Because I am not